# navigationcontroller not working properly going to another view controller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have two buttons which is the login and signup button and I programmatically code my UI not using storyboard when I am about to tap my login button it wont go to the `LoginController`here is my code. Is it because of the new SceneDelegate? 
[image]

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController{
         let loginButton = UIButton()
         let signUpButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

         setupLoginButton()
         setupSignUpButton()
         view.backgroundColor = .black
    }

func setupLoginButton(){
   loginButton.applyDesign()
   loginButton.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)

   loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

   view.addSubview(loginButton)
   loginButtonConstraints()
}

@objc func loginButtonTapped(){
 let nextScreen = LoginController()
 navigationController?.pushViewController(nextScreen, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I can't see. Can you add code in question?

Comment: @swifty2 i edited it go check it

Answer (score 0):

```
        let nextScreen = LoginController()
        let nextVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextScreen)
        nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Try this it will work.

Comment: @nani10 If it was work can you give a check for answer ?